# Access URL param from Input::get() with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('demo/{system?}', 'MonitorController@demo');
```

I am using it like so because I would like my url to look like so:

```
mysite.com/demo/spain-system
```

Where `spain-system` will be the variable I need to get.

Right now, I'm getting it like this:

```
public function demo($systemName = null){
}
```

But I would like to be able to access to it as if it were a URL parameter with `Input::get('system')` so I can access to it from other methods or even from other controllers such as `BaseController.php`.

Is there any way to achieve this? 
I've played around with `Route::input('system')` **but** then it doesn't work when I pass it as a get parameter (in other Ajax calls and so on)

## Update

In PHP we can get URL params by using the `$_GET` function and laravel provides the function `Input::get()` to do so as well.

If there were no routes in laravel, I would make use of `.htaccess` rewrite rules to change this:

```
mysite.com/demo/?system=spain-system
```

To this:

```
mysite.com/demo/spain-system
```

And I could still retrieve the variable `system` as a GET parameter by using `$_GET["system"]`.

That's kind of what I would expect of laravel, but it seems it is just treating it as the parameter of the `demo` method and not really as a URL variable.

Is there any way to keep treating it as a URL variable and at the same time use it in a *pretty URL* without the `?system=` ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you breefly explain what your problem is and what you want? Because now it's kind of unclear. You can edit the question.

Comment: I've just updated it.

Comment: i think i got ur point you want to get Input::get('sample') value into the parameter in controller? correct me if im wrong

Comment: Exactly. In a param in the controller method and as a GET param from any other place.

Answer (score 0):

So you actually just want to get an url like this? `mysite.com/demo/spain-system` instead of `mysite.com/demo/?system=spain-system`? Laravel provides that by default?

Look, When you want to get the router variable `{system?}` to be accesible you'll need to do this:

In your router:

```
Route::get('demo/{system}', 'MonitorController@demo');
```

Then you have an controller where this noods to stand in:

```
public function demo($system)
{
  //your further system
  //You are be able to access the $system variable
  echo $system; //just to show the idea of it.
}
```

When you now go to to `localhost/demo/a-system-name/`, You'll see a blank page with `a-system-name`.

Hope this helps, because your question is abit unclear.

Comment: Not what I asked. In fact, all your code is already in my question. I'm wondering how can i get `system` from any other method or controller, such as the constructor of Basecontroller AND at the same time, from the `demo` method's parameter.

Comment: Just think about it this way: **I want a GET parameter in the URL, but I want to display it in a pretty URL way without the `?system=`**

Comment: i think i got ur point you want to get Input::get('sample') value into the parameter in controller? correct me if im wrong.